# How to update data in the database using artisan Tinker

Tags: laravel, tinker

First,I call artisan tinker using the command below

```
$ php artisan tinker
```

Then, I plan to get all of the model in Admin to update the name as "admin", then I save the update by using command below

```
$admin = App\Admin::get()->name="admin"->save()

//Admin is my model
//name is the table structure of Admin table
//then I save it with save()
```

However, it pop out an error as shown below :-

> PHP Error:  Call to a member function save() on string in Psy Shell
>   code on line 1

Comment: give us your full code.

Comment: sir, can u specific which code u want..? Is it model code ?

Comment: No, it's ok. I just misunderstood.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With update method.

`$admin = App\Admin::query()->update(['name' => 'admin']);`

In `Admin` model:

```
protected $fillable = 'name';
```

Comment: Thank for the reply sir. But it show an error `PHP Deprecated:  Non-static method Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model::update() should not be called statically in Psy Shell code on line 1`

Comment: Try this at your project. Not in tinker. @HoWeiKang

Comment: Try again please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is that you're chaining a method on a string.

Use `update` next time, like this:

```
$admin = App\Admin::get()->update(['name' => 'admin'])
```

Read more on this [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#mass-updates).